# column space having non-linear combinations of basis vectors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector

I have a matrix $A_{3x3}$ whose basis for the column space are $a_{1}=(2,2,5)$, $a_{2}=(9,5,3)$ and $a_{3}=(3,6,1)$. If these are the basis for the column space, then column space can always be generated by linear combination of these basis vectors. Right?

Now, here is what I did.

I went for a non-linear combination of these basis vectors given by $a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}+a_{3}^{3}$ which is equal to $(40,225,29)$. Now since, $(40,225,29)$ is a non-linear combination of basis vectors, I should not be able to get this by linear combination of basis vectors. To verify this I tried to get the coefficients $x_{1},x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ such that $x_{1}(2,2,5)+x_{2}(9,5,3)+x_{3}(3,6,1) = (40,225,29)$. Surprisingly, I am getting a consistent solution.

Why is this discrepancy ? By definition the above system should have been inconsistent.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is this question in way related to the _software_ Wolfram Mathematica? Otherwise it would be a better fit on https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "Now since, (40,225,29) is a non-linear combination of basis vectors, I should not be able to get this by linear combination of basis vectors." Wrong premise.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You have been given an answer but your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a mathematical misunderstanding and it's unrelated to Wolfram Mathematica programming, and therefore is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2):

> By definition the above system should have been inconsistent.

This is a false premise: $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so *any* nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a nontrivial linear combination of $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$.